# 4d integral in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

I'm trying to evaluate the integral using MATLAB with an equation containing 4 related random variables, thus the boundaries of the integrals are not constant.

There are 2 exponential pdfs, and 2 other hyper exponential , and 1 Reyleigh CDF all multiplied together and with (x - y - z).

I'm trying to evaluate it using integral Q = (@(w) integral3(@(x,y,z,w),xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,zmin,zmax),wmin,wmax);

I'm getting an error always. this is my code down here :

```html
u_x = 10; %  rate!
x_th = .3;
sigma = 1.33;
u_y = 10;
u_w = 100;
a= 1;
fun = @(x,y,z,w) (x - y - z )*u_x*exp(-u_x*x)*u_y*exp(-u_y*y)*((a/(a+1))*(a*u_w)*exp(-a*u_w*w)+((1/(a+1))*(u_w/a))*exp(-u_w*w/a))*((a/(a+1))*(a*u_w)*exp(-a*u_w*z)+((1/(a+1))*(u_w/a))*exp(-u_w*z/a))*(1-exp(-x_th/sigma^2))

xmin = @(y)y;
xmax = @(y,w)y + w;
ymin = 0;
ymax = inf;
zmin = 0;
zmax = @(w) w;
wmin = 0;
wmax = inf;

Q = integral(@(w) integral3(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,zmin,zmax),wmin,wmax);
```

ERROR MESSAGE :

Error using integral3 (line 63)
XMIN must be a floating point scalar.

Error in numerical_int>@(w)integral3(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,zmin,zmax)

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 83)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AToInfInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

Error in numerical_int (line 28)
Q = integral(@(w) integral3(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,zmin,zmax),wmin,wmax);

Comment: Just did. Thank you

Comment: Why are xmin, xmax, zmax function handles?

Comment: I believe I didn't get you well, those are the triple integral boundaries of each random variable, x , y ,z in integral3. do I have an misunderstanding in the way this function shall be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `integral3()` requires **all** the ***lower bounds*** to be **real
  number**
- `int()` does not, but need to use ***syms function*** instead of ***function
  handle***
- For ***element-wise*** calculation use the ***dot***`.` operator followed by the
  concerned operator  [like](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html)

```
1)     * ---> .*           2)     / ---> ./                3) ^ ---> .^
```

> Read [this](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~jmr/241/tripleint.html) for more information on how to use `int()` for `nd`
>   integral

---

**The code is as follows**

```
syms x y z w
u_x = 10; %  rate!
x_th = .3;
sigma = 1.33;
u_y = 10;
u_w = 100;
a= 1;

fun = (x - y - z ).*u_x.*exp(-u_x*x).*u_y.*exp(-u_y.*y)...
    .*((a./(a+1)).*(a.*u_w).*exp(-a.*u_w.*w)+((1./(a+1)).*(u_w./a))...
    .*exp(-u_w.*w./a)).*((a./(a+1)).*(a*u_w)*exp(-a.*u_w.*z)...
    +((1./(a+1)).*(u_w./a))*exp(-u_w.*z./a)).*(1-exp(-x_th./sigma.^2));

xmin = y;
xmax = y + w;
ymin = 0;
ymax = inf;
zmin = 0;
zmax =  w;
wmin = 0;
wmax = inf;

% Integrate along x
intx = int(fun, x, xmin, xmax);

% Integrate along y
intxy = int(intx, y, ymin, ymax);

% Integrate along z
intxyz = int(intxy, z, zmin, zmax);

% Integrate along w
intxyzw = int(intxyz, w, wmin, wmax);

value = vpa(intxyzw, 3);

% 2.14e-5
```

Comment: Can you kindly comment on the final result, as it gave a piecewise similar relations, computing one of them gave a complex number with Infinity as the imaginary part

Comment: @MohamadMisto Answer updated, check it. I didn't mention the integrating variable before

Comment: I also added a link where you can see how `int()` is used for `3d` integral or more

Comment: Will have a look on it! Thanks!